# expect{ subject }.to change(...).by(1) doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This test passes:

```
it 'test' do
  old = parenthood.student.balance
  Payment.money_transfer_to_child current_user: parenthood.user,
                                  student_id: parenthood.student.id,
                                  amount: '1',
                                  comment: 'some comment'
  expect(parenthood.student.reload.balance).to eq(old+1)
end
```

changing it to the following form makes it not pass ("was changed by 0"):

```
subject { Payment.money_transfer_to_child current_user: parenthood.user,
                                              student_id: parenthood.student.id,
                                              amount: '1',
                                              comment: 'some comment' }
it { expect{ subject }.to change(parenthood.student.reload, :balance).by(1) }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that you figured out a way to make it work but maybe let's have a proper answer here. So first why it didn't work.

`it { expect{ subject }.to change(parenthood.student.reload, :balance).by(1) }`

When this line is executed what is done is (not exactly but roughly):

1. First the parameter of the change method are calculated. Which means that `parenthood.student.reload` is evaluated at that point.
2. The balance method is called on the object that was evaluated, and the value is remembered.
3. The block in expect (in this case only subject) is executed
4. Again the balance method is called on the object

The problem here is that `parenthood.student.reload` was evaluated before the `subject` was executed. After the execution of `subject` it was never calculated again as that was already passed to change method. That's why you were having the old value there.

What you can do is either have your solution (but it's not very elegant cause reloading parenthood is not part of what you are testing). Or you can use the block in change matcher and do something like:

```
it { expect{ subject }.to change { parenthood.student.reload.balance }.by(1) }
```

That syntax makes the block with `parenthood.student.reload.balance` evaluated both before running `subject` and after and should fix your test.

Answer (score 1):

Adding one line to the subject solved my problem:

```
subject { Payment.money_transfer_to_child current_user: parenthood.user,
                                              student_id: parenthood.student.id,
                                              amount: '1',
                                              comment: 'some comment'
              parenthood.student.reload }
```